# Animate Frames Over What Time?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to animate an image. It's a simple animation moving from left to right. This will eventually be a gif that is downloaded by the user.

I currently have this animation as 5 frames at 100ms each, but the animation looks a bit jittery. Then I increased to 20 frames of 50ms each, but still looks jittery. Wondering if there was any input on making easein / slidein animations smooth. Should I increase the frames even more?

**My Current Animation Is (Each Frame at 100ms)**
left: [x, x, x, x, x]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Animation is only smooth to the human eye at 60fps, which is about 16 milliseconds per frame. This is the default animation standard for most things on computer screens. It's also what window.requestAnimationFrame defaults to for frames per second, and you should use requestAnimationFrame for most browser based animation timing.

Comment: @AndyRay. 30fps does a fair job of fooling the eye.

Comment: Move smaller increments with each frame.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a CSS animation for this. It works smoother and the code can be simpler. Here is an example:

```
<style>
  #movie {
    transition-property: left;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function move(d) {
    d.style.left = '500px';
  }
</script>

<div id="movie" onclick="move(this)"></div>
```

Click on the red rectangle will smoothly move it right.